# Facing issue while running feature, specflow in visual studio, build error

Tags: c#, specflow

I have created a basic feature file and trying to execute my first program. I have installed all mandatory packages through NuGet.

Error received :

```
Error       The "GenerateFeatureFileCodeBehindTask" task failed unexpectedly.
System.Exception: Error when reading project file. ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized element 'unitTestProvider'.
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement.DeserializeElement(XmlReader reader, Boolean serializeCollectionKey)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection.DeserializeSection(XmlReader reader)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Configuration.ConfigurationSectionHandler.CreateFromXml(String xmlContent)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Configuration.ConfigurationLoader.Load(SpecFlowConfiguration specFlowConfiguration, ISpecFlowConfigurationHolder specFlowConfigurationHolder)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Generator.Configuration.GeneratorConfigurationProvider.LoadConfiguration(SpecFlowConfiguration specFlowConfiguration, SpecFlowConfigurationHolder specFlowConfigurationHolder)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Generator.Configuration.GeneratorConfigurationProviderExtensions.LoadConfiguration(IGeneratorConfigurationProvider configurationProvider, SpecFlowConfigurationHolder configurationHolder)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Generator.Project.ProjectReader.ReadSpecFlowProject(String projectFilePath, String rootNamespace)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Generator.Project.ProjectReader.ReadSpecFlowProject(String projectFilePath, String rootNamespace)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Generator.Project.MSBuildProjectReader.LoadSpecFlowProjectFromMsBuild(String projectFilePath, String rootNamespace)
   at SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.SpecFlowProjectProvider.GetSpecFlowProject()
   at SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.GenerateFeatureFileCodeBehindTaskExecutor.Execute()
   at SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.GenerateFeatureFileCodeBehindTask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() specflowFramework
```

my app.config looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
    </startup>
    
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="NUnit">
      <section name="TestRunner" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <section name="specFlow" type="TechTalk.SpecFlow.Configuration.ConfigurationSectionHandler, TechTalk.SpecFlow" />
  </configSections>
  <specFlow>
   <language feature="en-US" />
   <unitTestProvider name="MSTest" />

   
  </specFlow>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

The unit test providers are not configured anymore in the app.config with SpecFlow 3. You have to use the appropriate NuGet package. Doc link: https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Guides/UpgradeSpecFlow2To3.html#changes-to-how-unit-test-providers-are-configured

In your case, you have to add the `SpecFlow.NUnit` package to your project and adjust your app.config to

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
  </startup>
    
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="NUnit">
      <section name="TestRunner" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <section name="specFlow" type="TechTalk.SpecFlow.Configuration.ConfigurationSectionHandler, TechTalk.SpecFlow" />
  </configSections>
  <specFlow>
   <language feature="en-US" />   
  </specFlow>
</configuration>
```

The list of the correct NuGet package depending on your unit test runner is: https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Installation/Unit-Test-Providers.html

---

Full disclosure: I am a developer and maintainer of SpecFlow and SpecFlow+

Comment: But now .. while running feature i get issue is .nuget\packages\specrun.runner\3.3.41\tools\TechTalk.SpecFlow.Plus.RPC.dll" because it was not found. .nuget\packages\specrun.runner\3.3.41\tools\SpecFlow.Plus.Shared.dll and .nuget\packages\specrun.runner\3.3.41\tools\TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.dll  error whie executing .. i have added specflow and specflw.runner only and not specflow,nunit as nunit is already present

Comment: i have solved this issue , have copied these file outsideof folder net461

Comment: hi Andreas , i am executing my feature .build is success without any errors .. but now test is executing with following result. but nothingi s happening. i have read certain blogs and came accross updation on nunit adaptor to 3.15  and n unit to 3.12 . which is done. still facing the same issue. --------- Starting test discovery ----------

Comment: I think now it is best, that you open an issue at https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow